# Вызов LoaderManager с несколькими CursorLoader

Tags: android, cursor

Нужно отобразить список `ListView` и когда выбран элемент,  отобразить диалог и в нем отобразить другой список `ListView`  (материнские и дочерние элементы)

```
 static class GroupCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {
    DB db;

    public GroupCursorLoader(Context context, DB db) {
        super(context);
        this.db = db;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor loadInBackground() {
        Cursor cursor = db.getGroupAll();

        return cursor;
    }
}


static class DetailCursorLoader extends CursorLoader{
    DB db;

    public DetailCursorLoader(Context context, DB db) {
        super(context);
        this.db = db;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor loadInBackground() {
        Cursor cursor;
        cursor = db.getDetailAll();

        return cursor;
    }
}
```

Как работать с двумя курсорами? т.е. какой код должен быть в следующих методах:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new GroupCursorLoader(this, mDB);       
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    scAdapterForGroup.swapCursor(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    Log.d(LOG, "onLoadReset");
}
```

Comment: как насчет проверить `Loader<Cursor> loader` на `instanceOf`?

Comment: А в методе `onCreateLoader` возвращать курсор в зависимости от `id`

Comment: В дополнение к ответу @metalurgus - для управления загрузчиками используется класс `LoaderManager`, в котором указывается ID вызываемого загрузчика, например `getLoaderManager.initLoader(GROUP_LOADER_ID, null, this)`. Смотрите так же [офф.док по загрузчикам](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/components/loaders.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    if(id == GROUP_LOADER_ID) {
        return new GroupCursorLoader(this, mDB);       
    } else {
        return new DetailCursorLoader(this, mDB);
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    if(loader instanceof GroupCursorLoader) {
        scAdapterForGroup.swapCursor(data);
    } else {
        scAdapterForDetails.swapCursor(data);
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    Log.d(LOG, "onLoadReset");
}
```

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то как-то так

Comment: для получения ID вызванного загрузчика в методе `onLoadFinished()` используется метод `loader.getId()`.